# Why and how does list comprehension work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm still learning Python and I was trying to do this:

```
#values is a list of string digits
values = int(i) for i in values
```

But it threw a Syntax error so after some googling I tried this:

```
values = [int(i) for i in values]
```

But I'm having a hard time understanding why one works and the other doesn't. Can you help me understand?

Comment: List comprehension is a specifically defined aspect of the python syntax. The reason it works with brackets is because that's how the python grammar is defined. A list comprehension is that specific case. Having the `int(i) for i in values` on its own doesn't make sense grammatically in python; there's no valid construct like that. It's only valid within brackets, by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
values = int(i) for i in values
```

The above code with throw a syntax error because it is not correct Python syntax (for list comprehension). `int(i) for i in values` is a completely incorrect statement because there is no way Python knows how to combine, or construct, those 2 statements.

List comprehension statements are surounded by brackets `[  ]`, because those are what enclose lists (I'm sure you know that `[1, 2, 3]` is a list).

```py
values = [int(i) for i in values]
```

The above code uses list comprehension because it is surrounded by `[  ]`. The statement `for i in values` will go though the list called `values`, and one by one, assign a value to the variable `I`, for you to do something with. In this case, `int(i)` will convert the variable `I` and append, or add, to the `values` list. This line of code will in the end convert all the values in `values` to integers.

Answer (score 1):

The type of brackets around the comprehension ends up determining the type of the resulting collection, be it a list `[]`, set `{}`, or generator `()` (not to be confused with a `tuple`, which also uses parentheses)

All of the following are valid syntax, but the *type* of the result differs

```
# first, lets assume 'values' is a valid iterable...
values = range(10)

# list comprehension
values = [int(i) for i in values]
print(type(values))
# => <class 'list'>

# set comprehension
values = {int(i) for i in values}
print(type(values))
# => <class 'set'>

# generator comprehension
values = (int(i) for i in values)
print(type(values))
# => <class 'generator'>
```

Python also supports so-called "dictionary comprehensions" for creating dictionaries (key-values pairs) from two iterables (or a 2D list), but that's another answer for another question ;)